# Can't configure network on Ubuntu server using DRAC

Tags: networking, server

I have installed Ubuntu 14 server on my server using DRAC from Dell.

IP Addresses, Gateway, Netmask and were supplied by the server company.

I have tried to configure the network using DHCP.

I have tried setting up a static IP with the details I have.

But no matter what I do, I cant seem to make it work.

When I'm trying to `ping 8.8.8.8` I get:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

---

```
$ ifconfig -a
em1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr ec:f4:bb:d6:51:40
    inet addr:75.4.234.152  BCast:172.25.0.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
    inet6 addr: fe80::eef4:bbff:fed6:5140/64 Scope:Link
    UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
    RX packets:14488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0  frame:0
    TX packets:2469 errors:0    dropped:0   overruns:0  carrier:0
    collisions:0    txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:869280 (869.2 KB)  TX bytes:838134 (838.1 KB)
    Memory:dcb00000-dcbfffff

em2 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr ec:f4:bb:d6:51:41
    BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500    Metric:1
    RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0  frame:0
    TX packets:0 errors:0   dropped:0   overruns:0  carrier:0
    collisions:0    txqueuelen:1000
    RX bytes:0 (0.0 KB) TX bytes:0 (0.0 KB)
    Memory:dcc00000-dccfffff

em3 and em4 are the same like em2 just with 1 digit difference in the mac address

lo  Link encap:Local Loopback
    inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0

$ cat /etc/network/interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 75.4.234.152
netmask 255.255.252.0
network 152.25.0.152 #i have tried also without this
broadcast 152.25.0.255 #i have tried also without this
dns-nameservers 152.25.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

I have tried also without this

```
gateway 152.25.0.1
```

Comment: Run: sudo ifconfig -a, sudo ifconfig, sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces. Edit post and paste outputs.

Comment: thanks kyodake
ifconfig -a gives me:
http://pastebin.com/7JkWHayY

cat /etc/network/interfaces gives me:
http://pastebin.com/ccByMhhR

the data that i got from my servers company is:
Primary IP: 75.4.234.152
NAT IP: 152.25.0.152
Subnet Mask: 255.255.252.0
Gateway: 152.25.0.1

Comment: Someone else will be able to confirm, but I am pretty sure that your IP (75.4.234.152) has to be a subset of the network's IP (152.25.0.152). This is not currently the case and probably your issue.

Comment: thanks @Pieter please see updated pastebin: http://www.pastebin.com/u22rAAkX

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638264/problem-with-configure-network-on-ubuntu-server-using-drac#comment912503_638264), the problem was with the IP addresses the server company supplied to me.